# How read all rows into third level jqgrid/subGrid. please see the image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How can I read the files in the third level of this jqgrid/subGrid  3 level? I can read the rows of the first and second level but I do not know how to read the third level. Greetings.

I just need to read the third level grid.

[how do I read these rows.please see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ah7vv.jpg)

```html
         
  jQuery("#jqGrid").jqGrid({
    url:'Operaciones_Grilla.php?Op=700',
 datatype: "json",
 mtype: 'GET', 
height: 400,
width: 1100,
    colNames:['id','Sistema','Opciones_Sistema'],
    colModel:[
     {name:'id',index:'id', width:10,editable: false},
  {name:'Sistema',index:'Sistema',  width: 30, align: 'left',editable: true,editrules:{required:true},edittype:"select",editoptions:{dataUrl:'Operaciones_Grilla.php?Op=91',datatype: 'json',mtype: 'GET'}}, 
  {name:'Opciones_Sistema',index:'Opciones_Sistema', width:55,editable: true,editrules:{required:true}}

  
  
    ],
 
 cmTemplate: { editable: true,sortable: false },
    rowNum:8,
    rowList:[8,10,20,30],
    pager: '#jqGridPager',
    sortname: 'id',
 loadonce: true,
    viewrecords: true,
 multiselect: false,
    editurl: 'Operaciones_Grilla.php', // this is dummy existing url caption:"CRUD on Local Data"
 footerrow: true,
 userDataOnFooter : true,
 autoencode:true,
 caption: "Opciones de Sistema",
 cellEdit: false,
    hiddengrid: false,
    ignoreCase: true,
 subGrid: true,

  subGridOptions: { "plusicon" : "ui-icon-triangle-1-e",
                      "minusicon" :"ui-icon-triangle-1-s",
                      "openicon" : "ui-icon-arrowreturn-1-e",
                      "reloadOnExpand" : false,
                      "selectOnExpand" : true },
 
 
 subGridRowExpanded: function(subgrid_id, row_id) {
  var subgrid_table_id, pager_id;
  subgrid_table_id = subgrid_id+"_t";
  pager_id = "p_"+subgrid_table_id;
  $("#"+subgrid_id).html("<table id='"+subgrid_table_id+"' class='scroll'></table><div id='"+pager_id+"' class='scroll'></div>");
  jQuery("#"+subgrid_table_id).jqGrid({
   //url:"Operaciones_Grilla.php?Op=80&Filtro="+row_id,
   url:"Operaciones_Grilla.php?Op=700",
   datatype: "json",
   height: 150,
            width: 800,
   colNames: ['id','Opciones_Sistema','Menu'],
   colModel: [
    {name:"id",index:"id",width:10,key:true,editable: false},
    {name:"Opciones_Sistema",index:"Opciones_Sistema",width:30,editable: false, hidden:true},
    {name:"Menu",index:"Menu",width:30,editable: true,editrules:{required:true}}
   ],
      rowNum:20,
      pager: pager_id,
      height: '100%',
   editurl: 'Operaciones_Grilla.php', // this is dummy existing url caption:"CRUD on Local Data"
   footerrow: true,
   userDataOnFooter : true,
   autoencode:true,
   
   /***************************************/


   Here third level grid.
How do I read these rows ?????????? 

  /***************************************/


    subGrid: true,
     subGridOptions: { "plusicon" : "ui-icon-triangle-1-e",
                      "minusicon" :"ui-icon-triangle-1-s",
                      "openicon" : "ui-icon-arrowreturn-1-e",
                      "reloadOnExpand" : false,
                      "selectOnExpand" : true },
    
    
    
    
    caption: "Detalle de Opciones de Sistema",
             subGridRowExpanded: function(subgrid_id2, row_id2) {
  var subgrid_table_id2, pager_id2;
  subgrid_table_id2 = subgrid_id2+"_t";
  pager_id2 = "p_"+subgrid_table_id2;
  $("#"+subgrid_id2).html("<table id='"+subgrid_table_id2+"' class='scroll'></table><div id='"+pager_id2+"' class='scroll'></div>");
  jQuery("#"+subgrid_table_id2).jqGrid({
   //url:"Operaciones_Grilla.php?Op=90&Filtro="+row_id2,
   url:"Operaciones_Grilla.php?Op=700",
   datatype: "json",
   height: 150,
            width: 800,
   caption: "Detalle de Opciones del Menu",
   colNames: ['id','Menu','Opciones_Menu'],
   colModel: [
    {name:"id",index:"id",width:10,key:true,editable: false},
    {name:"Opciones_Menu",index:"Opciones_Menu",width:30,editable: false, hidden:true},
    {name:"Menu",index:"Menu",width:30,editable: true,editrules:{required:true}}
   ],
      rowNum:20,
      pager: pager_id2,
      height: '100%',
   editurl: 'Operaciones_Grilla.php', // this is dummy existing url caption:"CRUD on Local Data"
   footerrow: true,
   userDataOnFooter : true,
   autoencode:true
   
   
   

  });
```

Comment: The question is not sufficiently descriptive to provide an answer. You should clearly mention what you want, perhaps make a fiddle so that we can look at the code

Comment: see here [how to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$("#bedata").click(function() {

var grid = $('#jqGrid')[0], rows = grid.rows,cRows = rows.length, iRow, row, trClasses,xx=0;


    for (iRow = 0; iRow < cRows; iRow++) {

  
         row = rows[iRow]; // row.id is the rowid
   trClasses = row.className.split(' ');
     if ($(row).hasClass("jqgrow") > 0) 
  {
               
       sub_grilla="";
          sub_grilla='jqGrid_'+row.id+'_t_';


       } else if ($(row).hasClass("ui-subgrid")) {
  
          var subgridTable = $(row).find("table.ui-jqgrid-btable:first");
       var ret = jQuery(subgridTable).jqGrid('getGridParam',0);
       var registros =jQuery(subgridTable).jqGrid('getGridParam', 'records');
       var rows1 = jQuery(subgridTable).getDataIDs();
       for (var i = 0; i < rows1.length; i++) 
                              {
                                 var rowId = rows1[i];
                                 var rdata = jQuery("#"+sub_grilla+rows1[i]+"_t").jqGrid('getGridParam',0);
         var registros2 =jQuery("#"+sub_grilla+rows1[i]+"_t").jqGrid('getGridParam', 'records');
         var rows2 = jQuery("#"+sub_grilla+rows1[i]+"_t").getDataIDs();
         
         for (var z = 0; z < rows2.length; z++) 
                                 {
                                              var rowData3 = $("#"+sub_grilla+rows1[i]+"_t").jqGrid('getRowData', rows2[z]);
                            console.log(rowData3);
         }// end for
        
                                   
                             }// end for
       
  
       }// cierrra if
    
 }//cierra el for    
    

}); // cierra el boton
```